# How to correctly graphically ssh -X into docker container?

Tags: ssh, docker, x11

I'm trying to ssh into a running container with

```
ssh -X user@IP
ssh -Y user@IP
```

I've launched with

```
docker run -it image:latest /bin/bash -c 'sudo service ssh stop;sudo service ssh start;/bin/bash'
```

I'm able to ssh into the container, but I can't run a GUI application.  When I use echo $DISPLAY, I get localhost:10.0

I've tried dozens of solutions of ForwardX11, X11Forwarding, ForwardX11Trusted, etc.

I get this warning on login:

```
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
```

I read the because it's a warning, it can be ignored.  When trying to run a GUI application, I get

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyCan't open display: localhost:10.0
```

I've tried so many things but none have worked thus far.  What can I do?

Thanks.

Just in case, here's a verbose output:

```
j@laptop:~/Documents/tmp/Docker/docker-system> ssh -vY moos@192.168.1.100
OpenSSH_6.6, OpenSSL 0.9.8zc 15 Oct 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/j/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/j/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config line 49: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to - [-] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/j/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/j/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/j/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/j/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/j/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/j/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/j/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/j/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: An invalid name was supplied
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: An invalid name was supplied
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 9b:dc:35:c2:f3:5f:86:54:58:91:fa:87:cd:58:d9:bb
debug1: Host '-' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/j/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentication succeeded (none).
Authenticated to - ([-]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: No xauth program.
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
Last login: Thu May 19 15:15:45 2016 from -

j@3ce2104c8e2d:~$ gedit
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 4 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from ::1 39148
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
debug1: channel 1: free: x11, nchannels 2
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyCan't open display: localhost:10.0
```

Comment: What system do you have on your laptop? Do you have Xorg and all related tools installed in Docker?